# In which cases are merge-, heap- and quicksort useful?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, list, sorting, mergesort

I'm studying when which sorting algorithms are faster and more efficient. From what I've read so far about sort algorithms such as insertion sort, it is very efficient when you're working with small arrays and when they're nearly sorted or sorted as the runtime will average O(N).

A heap sort being a little trickier and using priority queue. It inserts things in to a priority queue and removes them. When using a heap it is prefered that the order of the list or whatever is reversed. A mergesort requires stability and works best on linked lists.

So my question is, when are these sorting algorithms more useful than the other? Because arguably I could use any, right? Which algorithm would I choose and based on what when for example having scenarios like these.

Say I have a small array with few elements and it's nearly sorted.

Big list with 2 million elements and they're sorted. You want to change say a few elements only.

A really big array with elements that are taking up big memory.

A list with a few hundred thousand elements that come in reverse sorting. Say I want to change position of a couple of thousand.

Comment: While one can make some educated guess, often you have to try and measure which algorithm works best in your situation.

Comment: One thing that will definitely inform your decision is whether you can fit the whole data into memory. There's a whole class of sorting algorithms (called "external sorting algorithms") optimised for the number of disk accesses needed rather than the number of comparisons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Say I have a small array with few elements and it's nearly sorted.

In the first case with a small array, there's no need to go with an advanced sorting algorithm like Merge sort or Quicksort. Bubble-, Selection- or Insertion sort is best here (considering overhead from recursion etc). And since it's almost sorted, Insertion sort will perform best because its best case is O(N).

> Big list with 2 million elements and they're sorted. You want to change say a few elements only.

Depends A LOT on what elements. Are they primitive types? If so, then comparing them isn't a big issue regarding time. If (let us assume we're using Java) they are self created objects, then comparing them can be really expensive in time. Comparing long Strings in Java can be really time consuming.

There are lots of elements, so the previous three simple algorithms will be ruled out (insertion-, bubble- and selection sort). You'd want to go with Merge sort or Quicksort.

Merge sort compares less than Quicksort, but moves around elements more. However, in this particular situation, I'd go with Merge sort, since choosing a pivot value in such large collection can really cost you lots and lots of time if we accidentally chose the lowest or largest value in the sorting order.

> A really big array with elements that are taking up big memory.

Again, what elements? Assuming you're almost out of memory, Quicksort is your choice. The overhead from recursive calls can be expensive, but in Java, that isn't too much of a problem *in this case*.

> A list with a few hundred thousand elements that come in reverse sorting. Say I want to change position of a couple of thousand.

Not a big suprise, but what is the type of the elements? This one is tricky. Here, we need to look at other factors too. I cannot really just say that one is better than another from only the given info.

Choosing correct sorting algorithms is a bit complex. What data structure are we using? If we have an array, indexing is fast, so we need to look at other factor. If we're using linked structures, perhaps we should avoid "indexing-based" algorithms as far as we can. These examples I've given are far from rules. They're more like guidelines. Choosing a good sorting algorithm is relative from case to case. Hope this helps at least a little.

Comment: These are just some examples I came up with on the go for the post but I feel like you've given me nudge in the right direction when thinking about which algorithm to choose. You're basically trying to adapt a certain algorithm to the scenario and sometimes they run very similarly and don't have a clear cut answer I guess.

Comment: @FreshJava Exactly. Sometimes it all depends on how much you're sorting. Sometimes it comes down to what you're sorting etc etc. Sometimes it's obvious, sometimes not. All is relative! Feel free to mark answer as "accepted" if you liked it :D